# Is it possible to show lync/skype for B presence indicator in outlook mail body?

Tags: html, email, outlook, lync, skype-for-business

I need to show **user presence indicator** in outlook mail **body**.

For ex: show not only user email in body text, but show user **online status and etc** like in from/to mail blocks.

I know how to do it by js/activeX on web pages, but what about mail body?
As I know mail message doesn't supp any execution code (for security reason).
Maybe there is some plugin like **skype click to call** but for lync?
Thank u for advices.